# scrollIntoView not working in appium for log scroll view. Throws no such element exception after one/two swipes

Tags: automation, appium-android, vertical-scroll

**Generic function for Scroll where** scrollablelist is the locator of scroll view in which we have to scroll

```
public void scrollToElementWithText(RemoteWebDriver driver, String scrollableList, String text) {

        MobileElement element = (MobileElement) driver
                .findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().resourceId(\""
                        + scrollableList + "\")).scrollIntoView(" + "new UiSelector().text(\"" + text + "\"))"));
    }
```

Comment: Sorry for type, its long scroll view.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code with in existing code `scrollable(true).instance(0))`

Add in desired capability `UiAutomator2` if you are using `appium` as `automation` engine.

```
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "UiAutomator2");
```

Now use below functions if you have element's id, and index as 0 for there is one element on page.

```
public void scrollByID(String Id, int index) {

        try {

             driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().resourceId(\""+Id+"\").instance("+index+"));")); 

        } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Scroll using Text**

```
public void scrollByText(String menuText) {

        try {

             driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textMatches(\"" + menuText + "\").instance(0));")); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Scroll using help of screen size:**

```
public void scrollToBottom() {

      int  x = driver.manage().window().getSize().width / 2;
      int start_y = (int) (driver.manage().window().getSize().height * 0.2);
      int end_y = (int) (driver.manage().window().getSize().height * 0.8);
        TouchAction dragNDrop = new TouchAction(driver)
                        .press(PointOption.point(x,start_y)).waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(Duration.ofMillis(500)))
                        .moveTo(PointOption.point(x, end_y))
                        .release();
        dragNDrop.perform();
    }
```

Comment: Same issue..tried scrollByText..it stopped after few swipes and threw no such element exception.

Comment: Updated the answer please check last solution. It is just scroll so after scroll you can perform required action